# C# XNA - How to draw animated texture with 2 Rectangle variables?

Tags: c#, animation, xna, rectangles, sprite-sheet

I have a problem which I need to resolve. I am making a Space Invaders game in C# XNA. I've been following this tutorial for the Invaders: https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=LLhsF03QfDMDhbw02_8C6Smg&v=wIW4S75iZBI&feature=player_detailpage#t=397
But I also have my own code for animating the Invader spritesheet. And eventually here's what I'm drawing:

```
void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch){
  for (int r = 0; r < m_InvaderRows; r++)
  {
    for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
    {
      spriteBatch.Draw(m_BotInvaderTex, m_BotInvaderPos, m_BotInvaderHitBox, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

      // ???

      spriteBatch.Draw(m_BotInvaderTex, m_BotInvadersRect[r, c], Color.White);
    }
  }
}
```

So the first `Draw()` call draws only 1 animated sprite. The second draws 50 non-animated sprites. `m_BotInvadersRect[r, c]` is a rectangle I used as a multi-dimensional array. So I'm looking for a way to combine both `Draw` calls and have 50 animated sprites drawn on my screen.

How can I animate the Invaders using a the code bellow?

My code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;

    namespace SpaceInvaders
    {
    class botInvader
    {

        public botInvader()
        {

        }

        public static Texture2D g_BotInvaderTex;
        Rectangle m_BotInvaderHitBox;
        public static Vector2 g_BotInvaderPos = new Vector2(0, 24);
        Vector2 m_BotInvaderOrigin;

        int m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame = 1;
        int m_BotInvaderFrameWidth = 52;
        int m_BotInvaderFrameHeight = 88;

        float m_Timer = 0f;
        float m_Interval = 100;

        Rectangle[,] m_BotInvadersRect;
        int m_InvaderRows = 5;
        int m_InvaderCollumns = 10;
        String m_BotInvadersDirection = "RIGHT";

        public void Initialize()
        {

        }

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            g_BotInvaderTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\gameGraphics\\gameSprites\\botInvaders\\normalInvaders\\spritesheet"); // invaderShip1
            m_BotInvadersRect = new Rectangle[m_InvaderRows, m_InvaderCollumns];
            for (int r = 0; r < m_InvaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Width = g_BotInvaderTex.Width;
                    m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Height = g_BotInvaderTex.Height;
                    m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X = 70 * c;
                    m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Y = 70 * r;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            m_BotInvaderHitBox = new Rectangle(m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame * m_BotInvaderFrameWidth, 0, m_BotInvaderFrameWidth, m_BotInvaderFrameHeight);
            m_BotInvaderOrigin = new Vector2(m_BotInvaderHitBox.X / 2, m_BotInvaderHitBox.Y / 2);

            m_Timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

            if (m_Timer > m_Interval)
            {
                m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame++;
                m_Timer = 0f;
            }

            if (m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame == 2)
            {
                m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame = 0;
            }

            m_BotInvaderHitBox = new Rectangle(m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame * m_BotInvaderFrameWidth, 0, m_BotInvaderFrameWidth, m_BotInvaderFrameHeight);
            m_BotInvaderOrigin = new Vector2(m_BotInvaderHitBox.Width / 2, m_BotInvaderHitBox.Height / 2);

            int m_RightSide = 800;
            int m_LeftSide = 0;

            for (int r = 0; r < m_InvaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    if (m_BotInvadersDirection.Equals ("RIGHT"))
                    {
                        m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X = m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X + 1;
                    }

                    if (m_BotInvadersDirection.Equals("LEFT"))
                    {
                        m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X = m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X - 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            String m_BotInvadersChangeDirection = "N";

            for (int r = 0; r < m_InvaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    if (m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X + m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Width > m_RightSide)
                    {
                        m_BotInvadersDirection = "LEFT";
                        m_BotInvadersChangeDirection = "Y";
                    }

                    if (m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X < m_LeftSide)
                    {
                        m_BotInvadersDirection = "RIGHT";
                        m_BotInvadersChangeDirection = "Y";
                    }
                }

                if (m_BotInvadersChangeDirection.Equals("Y"))
                {
                        for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
                        {
                            m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Y = m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Y + 3;
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < m_InvaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(g_BotInvaderTex, g_BotInvaderPos, m_BotInvaderHitBox, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
                    spriteBatch.Draw(g_BotInvaderTex, m_BotInvadersRect[r, c], Color.White);
                }
            }         
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a call for creating sprite like in this tutorial --> [enter link description here](http://codeforcake.com/blog/?p=142). In this class yoo have also to put the animation

```html
 m_BotInvaderHitBox = new Rectangle(m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame * m_BotInvaderFrameWidth, 0, m_BotInvaderFrameWidth, m_BotInvaderFrameHeight);
            m_BotInvaderOrigin = new Vector2(m_BotInvaderHitBox.X / 2, m_BotInvaderHitBox.Y / 2);

            m_Timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

            if (m_Timer > m_Interval)
            {
                m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame++;
                m_Timer = 0f;
            }

            if (m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame == 2)
            {
                m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame = 0;
            }

            m_BotInvaderHitBox = new Rectangle(m_BotInvaderCurrentFrame * m_BotInvaderFrameWidth, 0, m_BotInvaderFrameWidth, m_BotInvaderFrameHeight);
            m_BotInvaderOrigin = new Vector2(m_BotInvaderHitBox.Width / 2, m_BotInvaderHitBox.Height / 2);

            int m_RightSide = 800;
            int m_LeftSide = 0;

            for (int r = 0; r < m_InvaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    if (m_BotInvadersDirection.Equals ("RIGHT"))
                    {
                        m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X = m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X + 1;
                    }

                    if (m_BotInvadersDirection.Equals("LEFT"))
                    {
                        m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X = m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X - 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            String m_BotInvadersChangeDirection = "N";

            for (int r = 0; r < m_InvaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    if (m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X + m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Width > m_RightSide)
                    {
                        m_BotInvadersDirection = "LEFT";
                        m_BotInvadersChangeDirection = "Y";
                    }

                    if (m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X < m_LeftSide)
                    {
                        m_BotInvadersDirection = "RIGHT";
                        m_BotInvadersChangeDirection = "Y";
                    }
                }

                if (m_BotInvadersChangeDirection.Equals("Y"))
                {
                        for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
                        {
                            m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Y = m_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Y + 3;
                        }
                }
            }
```

and Finally you have to follow the tutorial and create a list of this object and in the draw method draw each items of list.

Comment: in the draw method of Game1.cs